# Highmaps: how can I show an ordered list of U.S. states with population density

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am playing with Highmaps. Here is the example Highmap with U.S. states and their population density:

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis

It would be nice if I can have a button to click and show an ordered list of states with population density. This would give a much easier and better idea of ordering than on a map.

Is this something out of box? Any pointer is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you just mean a table with state and population density? What should your ordered list look like?

Comment: If you would like to sort your list by name, you can use javaScript sort method. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/cc84hk3n/1/

Comment: wergeld, thanks for your question. I want the list to be ordered based on the density. Either direction is ok. It doesn't have to be a table, but a table would be nice.

Comment: Grzegorz, thanks for your example. I would like to sort on the density, not by name. Your example seems to be what I am looking for. Could you please make an answer so that I can select?

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should be able to sort your data using js sort method. 
Here you can find more information about this method: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/sort

You can make custom compare method for comparing elements of your array. For example if you would like to compare your data by name:

```
  function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1
    return 0
  }
```

Here you can find an example how this method may work with you chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/cc84hk3n/2/

You may sort your data by value as well if you would like to.

Best,

Comment: Grzegorz, I notice one issue. If I start with this country-level link http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/all-maps# I am able to see the correct sorting by using your method. However, when I drill down to the states, then I still see the country-level sorting. Anyway to see the state-level sorting when I drill down? Thanks!

Comment: I got it solved. It seem that when drilling down to a lower level, the added function(chart) will be called more than once and you need to detect which   call with the correct chart data. Cheers!